# Open External Page in Popup in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm using jQuery Mobile. Actually i want open an externl link in a popup. 
I tried this.

```
<a href="#" id="dialoglink"  data-rel="dialog">Open Dialog</a>
<script>
$(document).delegate('#dialoglink', 'click', function() {
    $(this).simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'blank',
        'prompt': false,
        'forceInput': false,
        'useModal':true,
        'fullHTML' : 
            'http://www.google.com/'
    })
});
</script>
```

It is opening a popup the content is the text http://www.google.com/.
But i actually want to load the url. i.e google index page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an ajax request:

```
$.get('http://url.to.load.net',function(data) {
    $(this).simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'blank',
        'prompt': false,
        'forceInput': false,
        'useModal':true,
        'fullHTML' : data
    });  
});
```

Nothing to recommend though, to do this with a whole page like google.com. simpledialog can't handle this type of content and it would destroy your markup structure. But you can load small pieces of HTML, like a list-view.