# in an android app how to open an external link in firefox (or user-chosen browser)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Phonegap + JQuerymobile to develop an Android app.

I wish to open an external link on an external browser (say Firefox, or Chrome; or let the user choose the browser).

How can I achieve this?

I have tried, without achieving desired results:

```
<a href="https://mylink.com" data-role="button" onclick="window.open('https://mylink.com', '_system'); return false;">mylink.com</a>
```

I also use '_blank', but I don't really see the difference.

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

I've done some research, but have not found yet an answwer. I've also checked this questions, but they don't seem to solve my problem:

1. [Links don't open in external browser in JQuery Mobile with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741634/links-dont-open-in-external-browser-in-jquery-mobile-with-phonegap): attributes _blank and _system don't seem to make a difference in my app
2. [Open External Page in Popup in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225453/open-external-page-in-popup-in-jquery-mobile): this is using an HTML popup
3. [Force iOS app opens external links in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138721/force-ios-app-opens-external-links-in-safari): this is for iOs apps
4. [Opening links in external device browser with Cordova/jQuery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395718/opening-links-in-external-device-browser-with-cordova-jquery-mobile): again the _system parameter, which doesn't show the list of browser for the user to choose from (not it's my default Chrome browser either)
5. other google searches

Comment: have you tried `rel="external"` instead of `onlick`?

Answer (score 1):

This did the job: using `navigator.app.loadUrl()`

full example:

```
<a href="#null" data-role="button" onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('https://mylink.com/', { openExternal:true }); return false;" target="_system"></a>
```

(taken from: [Opening an url in a new browser window in Android working with PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417004/opening-an-url-in-a-new-browser-window-in-android-working-with-phonegap))

Comment: This is the only one that has worked for me from Android 2.3.6 and Up using PhoneGap 3.X